# How do I change the audio balance on android 7.1.2?

Tags: settings, audio, music, headphones

I have conductive hearing loss in my right ear, and I'm wondering if there is a way without rooting, for me to adjust the balance to make my music sound correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only related option I can see on stock Android 7.0 is to enable "Mono audio" (under Settings > Accessibility). (FWIW, I see that iOS 10 has the option to change "balance" out of the box.)